# Replace data.frame column names with a string in corresponding lookup table

Tags: r, dataframe, names

I have the following data.frame:

```
set.seed(126)
df <- data.frame(a=sample(c(1:100, NA), 10), b=sample(1:100, 10), c=sample(1:100, 10), d = c(1:10))
    a  b  c  d
1  18 27 53  1
2  44 16 66  2
3  58 47  3  3
...
```

And the following lookup table:

```
varnames <- data.frame(old = c("a", "b", "c"), new = c("dog", "cat", "mouse"))
  old   new
1   a   dog
2   b   cat
3   c mouse
```

What I am trying to do is replace the `names(df)` with the corresponding `varnames$new`... If a `names(df)` is not in `varnames$old`, then retain the colname in df...

The resulting data.frame I would like returned would look like this:

```
   dog cat mouse  d
1   57  10    83  1
2   53  99    94  2
3   99  60    39  3
...
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about using the `match()` function

```
mm <- match(names(df), varnames$old)
names(df)[!is.na(mm)] <- as.character(varnames$new[na.omit(mm)])
head(df)
#   dog cat mouse d
# 1  65  48    19 1
# 2  46  15    80 2
# 3  NA  47    84 3
# 4  68  34    46 4
# 5  23  75    42 5
# 6  92  87    68 6
```

If you are interested, you could also use the `dplyr` `rename()` function

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% rename_(.dots=with(varnames, setNames(as.list(as.character(old)), new)))
```

Or one more option, the `data.table` package has a `setnames` function

```
library(data.table)
setnames(df, as.character(varnames$old), as.character(varnames$new))
```

Comment: I think in case that `varnames` never has column names that aren't present in `df` (just like you assumed in your `setnames` implementation, otherwise it won't work), you could simplify your first two lines to just `names(df)[match(varnames$old, names(df))] <- as.character(varnames$new)`. Nice implementation of `setnames` btw.

Comment: @DavidArenburg actually the `data.table` version of `setnames` doesn't assume all values are present in the replacement vector. All the above methods should be equivalent as written.

Comment: What I meant is that if you will change `varnames` to let say `varnames <- data.frame(old = c("l", "b", "c"), new = c("dog", "cat", "mouse"))`, your base R approach will still work as expected, while `setnames` will fail.

Answer (score 2):

One more option is `mapvalues()` from the plyr package:

```
library(plyr)
names(df) <- mapvalues(names(df),
                             from = varnames$old,
                             to = as.character(varnames$new))
```

If you are using the dplyr package, you can call this with `plyr::mapvalues()` so you don't have to load plyr on top of dplyr (which causes problems).