# How do I update data from an incomplete lookup table?

Tags: r

I have a table that uses unique IDs but inconsistent readable names for those IDs. It is more complex than month names, but for the sake of a more simple example, let's say it looks something like this:

```
demo_frame <- read.table(text=" Month_id Month_name Number
1   Jan 37
2   Feb 63
3   March   9
3   Mar 150
2   February    49", header=TRUE)
```

Except that they might have spelled "Feb" or "March" eight different ways. I also have a clean data frame that contains consistent names for the names that have variations:

```
month_lookup <- read.table(text=" Month_id Month_name
2   Feb
3   Mar", header=TRUE)
```

I want to get to this:

```
1   Jan 37
2   Feb 63
3   Mar 9
3   Mar 150
2   Feb 49"
```

I tried `merge(month_lookup, demo_frame, by = "Month_id")` but that dropped all the January values because "Jan" doesn't exist in the lookup table:

```
 Month_id Month_name.x Month_name.y Number
1        2          Feb          Feb     63
2        2          Feb     February     49
3        3          Mar        March      9
4        3          Mar          Mar    150
```

My read of [How to replace data.frame column names with string in corresponding lookup table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654065/how-to-replace-data-frame-column-names-with-string-in-corresponding-lookup-table) is that I ought to be able to use `plyr::mapvalues` but I'm unclear from examples and documentation on how I'd map the `id` to the `name`. I don't just want to say "Replace 'March' with 'Mar'" -- I need to say `SET month_name = 'Mar' WHERE month_id = 3` for each value in lookup.

Comment: Why not just merge the two tables together?

Comment: Sorry. Should have included where `merge` failed. Fixed.

Comment: Just add Jan to the lookup table? A lookup table is easy to generate with `data.frame(month.abb = month.abb, Month_id = 1:12)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this.

```
library(dplyr)

demo_frame <- read.table(text=" Month_id Month_name Number
1   Jan 37
2   Feb 63
3   March   9
3   Mar 150
2   February    49", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

month_lookup <- read.table(text=" Month_id Month_name
2   Feb
3   Mar", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

result = 
  demo_frame %>%
  rename(bad_month = Month_name) %>%
  left_join(month_lookup) %>%
  mutate(month_fix =
           Month_name %>%
           is.na %>%
           ifelse(bad_month, Month_name) )
```